# The interpretation of expected time bound for searches in a hash table

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, hashtable, clrs

As CLRS book,page 260 stated,

> [image]

I wouldn't have any problem if the author says the bound is eventually
[image]
or even
[image]
What kind of theories shall we apply to simplify the original result, i.e, cancelling the factor ***1/n*** of ***a***. Since ***n*** is one of inputs of the function, is it necessary to cancel it by treating it as a constant? What i've missed? is anyone got the same confusion T_T?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alpha/n` is asimptotically smaller (has lower order) being compared with `alpha`, so it might be ignored. When `n` (hashtable size, AFAIU) becomes larger, `1/n` value tends to zero.
Note - [wiki table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) does not contain `1/n` function because it is evaluated as having zero impact

Alike situation - if time is `Theta(n^2 + 100*n + 10000)`, dominating summand is quadratic, and

```
Theta(n^2 + 100*n + 10000)` = Theta(n^2)
```